# Multiple Line Transitions - from x lines to y lines in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to have a multiple line graph transition from a set of x number of lines to set of y number of lines. After going through many examples (both from here at stackoverflow and from the wider web) I am still stumped. Please help me with what I'm sure is an easy fix.

Relevant Code:

```
    //--line generators
    var line_main = d3.svg.line()
        .defined(function (d) {
        return d.value != isNaN(d.value);
    }) //--deals with NAN but results in a y range extending to 0
    .x(function (d) {
        return x_main(d.date);
    })
        .y(function (d) {
        return y_main(d.value);
    });

    var svg = d3.select('#discharge-graph').append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'graph')
        .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    var main = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    update();

    function update() {
        //--reset plot elements
        d3.selectAll("path.line").remove(); //--trying to use transitions instead of this

        //--paths for main areas
        main.selectAll('path.line')
            .data(sets)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', function (d) {
            return line_main(d.values);
            })
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .style('stroke', function (d) {
            return colour(d.name);
        });
    };
```

I have tried many variations where I comment out this line:

```
        d3.selectAll("path.line").remove();
```

and add one or more of the lines of code that are commented out below:

```
    //--paths for main areas
    main.selectAll('path.line')
    //d3.transition(main).select('path.line')
    //.transition().duration(600)
        .data(sets)
        //.transition().duration(600)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', function (d) {
        return line_main(d.values);
    })
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .style('stroke', function (d) {
        return colour(d.name);
    });
```

The result is always a blank canvas. The complete code as it stands is at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjustin7/RNGUa/).  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.